# In Python, how to yield the results of the call to another class's function?

Tags: python, grpc-python, haystack

Very little experience of Python, struggling with the best pattern here.

I have a generator function, and I would like this function to `yield` the return value of another function until exhausted. This is using the streaming feature of [Haystack's PromptNode](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/prompt_node#streaming), although that's really neither here nor there, just the pattern I'm after.

It is a little chatbot whose results I am trying to stream using gRPC. That bit is working, it's just getting it to `yield` correctly.

My generator looks like this:

```
class ChatBot(chat_pb2_grpc.ChatBotServicer):

    def AskQuestion(self, request, context):
        query = request.query
        custom_handler = GRPCTokenStreamingHandler()
        prompt_node = PromptNode(
            "gpt-4",
            default_prompt_template=lfqa_prompt,
            api_key=api_key,
            max_length=4096,
            model_kwargs={"stream": True, "stream_handler": custom_handler}
        )

        pipe = Pipeline()
        pipe.add_node(component=retriever, name="retriever", inputs=["Query"])
        pipe.add_node(component=prompt_node, name="prompt_node", inputs=["retriever"])

        output = pipe.run(query=query)

        # This should yield the "return token_received" from custom_handler
        #     yield chat_pb2.Response(token=token, final=False)

        yield chat_pb2.Response(token="", final=True)
```

And my `GRPCTokenStreamingHandler` looks like this:

```
class GRPCTokenStreamingHandler(TokenStreamingHandler):

    def __call__(self, token_received, **kwargs) -> str:
        return token_received
```

The way the `PromptNode` functions is that the `output`, where ordinarily it would print token after token to the console, is instead directed to this `GRPCTokenStreamingHandler` class.

So each of those `token_received` should be `yield`ed by the `AskQuestion` generator.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you really need a generator to accomplish your goal in this case.

If you want to stream token by token you must send the received token via gRPC in your custom `GRPCTokenStreamingHandler`.

The streaming handler is used by the `PromptNode` internally and called each time part of the streamed response is received from ChatGPT in this case.

`Pipeline.run()` is blocking also, when that returns it means that you received all the tokens you could have received.